# Amazon MWS API for historic promotion data

Tags: api, amazon-mws, promotions

I want to download all amazon fba promotion data (ID, discount value and order no applied to ) of promotions run in the past preferably using MWS. I tried _GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CUSTOMER_SHIPMENT_PROMOTION_DATA_ report but no data is being retrieved. First step GetAmazonData is not creating the flatfile header or returning any rows. Error thrown is : exited with error code zero.

I also created an api for All Orders (_GET_FLAT_FILE_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_) but this does not return historic data or atleast even data from last 90 days as amazon generally stored data for that duration. 
My Question is: Is there any other way to get past promotion ID for FBA products in a report ? If I need to use _GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CUSTOMER_SHIPMENT_PROMOTION_DATA_ what could be the issue that api step 1 is not running?